# Setting of different text colors for different UITabBarItem's in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, ios15, xcode13

After update to iOS 15, I implemented UITabBar configuration this way:

```
    let backgroundColor = UIColor.grey
    let selectedItemTextColor = UIColor.blue
    let unselectedItemTextColor = UIColor.black
    
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor]
        tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor]
        tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    } else {
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor], for: .selected)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor], for: .normal)
        tabBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
    }
```

This works fine for iOS 15 and older versions.

But in my project I need to set selected/unselected text color for one of tab bar items, different from other items. Set it in runtime.

There are 5 tab bar items. In some moment, I need this behavior: four of them should have blue/black text color (for selected/unselected states) and one should have red/green color.

Until iOS 15, I used this code to set colors of needed item in every moment of time:

```
let indexOfItemToChange = 4
tabBar.items[indexOfItemToChange].setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .selected)
tabBar.items[indexOfItemToChange].setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: UIColor.green], for: .normal)
```

After update update to iOS 15 it makes no effect. I have tried to set it like this:

```
let indexOfItemToChange = 4
tabBar.items[indexOfItemToChange].standardAppearance?.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
tabBar.items[indexOfItemToChange].standardAppearance?.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.red]
```

But it makes no effect too. Even if before setting of tab bar item colors I set UITabBar appearances for each tab bar item:

```
tabBar.items.forEach {
$0.standardAppearance = standardAppearance
$0.scrollEdgeAppearance =  scrollEdgeAppearance
}
```

Some one faced this issue? Any advice?

PS. In my project there are no xibs and storyboards. So I need to solve my problem only programmatically.

Comment: Are you able to find any solution or workaround for this issue? I am facing the same problem in my project. I want to set different badge colour for different tab bar item.